# Tabulator cell click: How to call a function in angular on cell click and use component elements

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, tabulator

I am trying to use Tabulator for tables in angular 7. I am trying to call a function on cell click such that the function should open a MatDialog box and display row information. However, the problem is that when I try to access any of the Component variables (dialog: MatDialog) inside the called function, it is undefined. On debugging I found that the function is called inside the Tabulator and not in the angular component. Is there a way to call a function in the Angular and access component variables inside the function?

```
export class ExampleTableComponent implements OnInit {
exampleTable: Tabulator;

 constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

ngOnInit() {

    this.exampleTable = new Tabulator("#ex-table-div",{
      height : 300,
      data: this.example_data,
      layout: "fitColumns",
      columns: [
        { formatter:"rownum", align:"center", width:40},
        { formatter: this.printIcon, width:40, align:"center", 
         cellClick: this.openDialog
        },
        .......
      ],
      ......
    });
}


openDialog(e, cell){

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

          dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
          dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

          this.dialog.open(DetailsComponent, {      
            width: '300px',
          });

     ..........
  }
......
}
```

Comment: Did you try lamda ? `cellClick: () => this.openDialog()`

Comment: @Gilsdav: It worked! Can please explain how you found the fix? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 introduce `lambda` also called `arrow function`. The main deference is the scope of `this`.

- function: scope of `this` = caller (Tabulator)
- lambda: scope of `this` = classe where the lambda is (ExampleTableComponent)

It can be done without this ES6 syntax using `cellClick: this.openDialog.bind(this)` but I personally prefer lambda.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Great! thanks for the explanation. With lamda function I was also able to pass the event and cell parameters, like cellClick: (e, row)=> this.openDialog(e, row). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I also had that problem. Here’s how I solved it:

```
cellClick: (e, row)=> this.openDialog(e, row)
```

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With Tabulator Version 5.0.10 I did like this:

this.tabulator.on("cellClick", (e, row)=> this.setSelection(e, row))

where setSelection is inside the methods part.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).